# Svelte 500 error when using Flowbite-svelte-icons

Tags: npm, import, reference, package, sveltekit

I'm getting an error 500 when attempting to reference the flowbite-svelte-icons. I've gone though the install process several times to ensure I didnt miss anything but I'm stuck here. I cant seem to use any icons from hero icons or the flowbite-svelte-icons packages without this error.

- tried several ways of referencing the package
- expected IntelliSense to help with importing.
- uninstalled and reinstalled the packages in question.
- image of code that is broken

Comment: What is the error? (Check dev server terminal output.)